# Is there any option to check if email id exists or not using python script?

Tags: python, smtp

I have a code where emails are being sent to the given ID using smtp and 
if the mail id does not exists then mail wont get delivered.
So, I want to capture the email ID's if they do not exist. Can this be done by python script?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a package called [validate_email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email). The following code returns a boolean:

```
validate_email('example@example.com')
```

Comment: it gives me this error- "'module' object is not callable"

Comment: @KomalMadamwar - Because you're probably doing exactly what the error is telling you. You're trying to call a module object. Make sure you do this as your import: `from validate_email import validate_email`

Comment: Ohh yes!! I got that corrected now. thanks :-) I was just adding import validate_email, that was the reason for this error

Comment: Please select this answer as the correct one then!